# To building a jQuery web widget for other domains

Tags: php, jquery

I spent two days to develop a web widget for other domains but I didn't get any success. I found a [tutorial](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) to develop a widget that is quite useful but my problem is:

If user clicks on my widget button then the widget will check the login status. If the user is not loggedin then a popup window will open and ask for username and password. If the user successfully logged in to widget origin then the parent window will automaticaly refresh and show the data on the place of widget button.

I have created the widget in jQuery to open the popup window but not able to refresh the parent window of popup.

Comment: Have you tried to use the jQuery.ui.dialog() instead of a popup window or are you dead set on a popup?

Comment: What's the problem? "I have created the widget in jQuery to open the popup window but not able to refresh the parent window of popup.", are you simply trying to refresh the `parent window`? And what is working? Can you show us an example?

Comment: @Richard:I have a search widget placed at http://www.testmemorial.in/widget/example.html and this search widget is coming from different domain http://www.darsean.com:8083.when the user clicked on search button the widget will check the authentication if the user is not logged in at  http://www.darsean.com:8083 the widget will open a popup window and this popup window contains login box .These steps are working.But if the user successfully authenticated I need to display their information at http://www.testmemorial.in/widget/example.html, which is stored at http://www.darsean.com:8083.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to reload the parent window to properly display data there.

This is the code I use in one of my projects and works in all tested browsers:

```
 <script>window.opener.location.reload(true);self.close()</script>
```

Alternatively you can look for a solution where you update DOM elements of the `window.opener`

Comment: we can not use window.opener.location.reload(true); because pop up window belongs to different domain.it will give permission denied error

Comment: ah yes, of course. But you could use the window.open and not link to a page, but only send HTML (http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus). That HTML could do another JS request like your other solution that `document.write()`'s the close :-)